# Access to contacts on the phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a work-around to get the details of a contact in the Phone's contacts?
With the api you can only access the email and phonenumber but that is definitely not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, access to additional contact information is not available.

This was a deliberate design decision to protect the security of a persons contacct information and to prevent applications getting access to this data without the users knowledge.

It has, however, been hinted that additional contact details will be available in future versions of the platform.

If you really need more details about a contact you will have to wait until the API is extended in this area.

Comment: I think this is a very stupid decision of the dev team but ok we will have to live with it. thanks for the post

Comment: We might see single contact api's expanded a bit. I initially read your question as wanting broad contact list info. Some of the api's are a little "just the essentials" at the moment, but I'm sure this will improve in time.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, if it doesn't improve - all the way to full (at least readonly) access to all contact details it is discouraging and stifling a great deal of good apps that should be made...

Many app developers would reject it for this reason alone...